# set value of first result of list, but not the rest

Tags: c#

I want to select and set the first value of the results from this list, but not the rest.

```
     var list = new List<ListItem>();
     service call--> brings back items
     var items = itemsFromService.tolist();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    ListItem currentItem = new ListItem(item);
    list.Add(currentItem);
}
Controller.SetItemDate(item); //only want this for the first result
return list.ToArray();
```

Comment: What? Why are you adding to the list inside the loop? It should be giving you a collection modified exception.

Comment: is your code even compiling?

Comment: Why are you looping through the list? You should be able to just do: `Controller.SetItemDate(list.First());`

Comment: when you think the loop step by step through: when is it supposed to end? it's like a donkey running behind a carrot on a stick which is strapped on his back

Comment: Yes, this works and returns what I need perfectly - why would you vote this down? It's a simple question, how to set the first item of the list.

Comment: @itsme86 it returns a list, that's why I'm looping. I'm not looping in order to  set the first item.

Comment: @MongZhu the loop ends when theres no more items in the list. lol, the loop isn't really relevant in this question.

Comment: @SAshurex Ah you changed your posted code. This should work. I figured that it is not important, that's why I did not mention it in the answer. Just commented on a loop through a list which is constantly expanding :)

Comment: @SAshurex I adopted my answer to your edit

Answer (score 1):

there is a nice method to get the first element in a list:

```
Controller.SetItemDate(items.First()); 
return list.ToArray();
```

**EDIT:**

after you have changed the code, I adapt my answer. This code should suffice
to perform your desired action:

```
service call--> brings back items
var items = itemsFromService.ToList();

Controller.SetItemDate(item.First()); //only want this for the first result
return item.ToArray();
```